# Docker-compose multiple instances on a single host machine

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration

This is how my docker file looks like

```
version: "3"
services:
  controller:
    build: ./cd_controller
    image: cd_controller:latest
    env_file: $PWD/robot-configurations/.env
    cap_add:
      - ALL
    links:
      - test_fixture
    volumes:
      - dependencypackages:/root/dependency-packages
      - robotconfigurations:/root/robot-configurations
    container_name: controller_g5
  test_fixture:
    image: docker-standard-all.ur-update.dk/ur/pytest-ur:0.7.1
    volumes:
      - pytestfixture:/workspace
      - controllertests:/workspace/controller-tests
    entrypoint: /workspace/entrypoint.sh
    container_name: test_fixture
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t
volumes:
  robotconfigurations:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: $PWD/robot-configurations
      o: bind
  ...
```

Basically it has two two services/containers controller&test_fixture. controller has source code running and test_fixture contains all the test_cases. test_fixture needs to talk to controller through a socket. Since docker-compose creates a network among its containers, in my py-test cases I am simply using

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("controller_g5", 30001)) # controller_g5 is name of the controller container
```

So far every thing look fine. But I realized that I have multiple versions/features of the source code. So I would like to create a multiple instances of a same thing each have their own network. Does naming the container blocks the container creation with same name in different network ?  Also I am not sure how to spin up one more network with similar container on the same host machine. I came across [Multiple isolated environments on a single host](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#multiple-isolated-environments-on-a-single-host) But couldn't manage to get a sample example.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to use a different project name. By default compose uses the directory name in which your project is as the project name. `docker-compose` takes care of setting up the isolated network appropriately for each project.

To create two instances of your project namespaced as "dev" and "test", you can run it as follows:

```bash
docker-compose -p dev up
docker-compose -p test up
```

From https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/

```
-p, --project-name NAME     Specify an alternate project name
                              (default: directory name)
```

You need to remove `container_name` field for multiple project instances to work. Compose prepends the container names with project name automatically but it won't do it if `container_name` is specified. You would get container name conflict when starting another project from the compose file if `container_name` is used. After removing `container_name`, your services will get service names as hostnames.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  It is very much close to the solution that I am looking for.  Running the docker-compose with project name is not allowing to set fixed `container names: test_fixture/controller_g5` It looks like the container name has to be unique irrespective of network.  Can you suggest a way to access other container in the network with out specifying container name  `s.connect(("dev_controller_1", 30001))`

Comment: You need to remove `container_name` field to fix the container name conflict. Compose will prepend the project name automatically to containers usually unless `container_name` is specified. Your service will get hostnames same as the service names (controller and test_fixture) after removing the `container_name` field. If you have hardcoded the service host name as `controller_g5` in code, then you rename the service to `controller_g5`.

Comment: `dev_controller_1` . I am worried about the tailing number 1.  The first container is name ends with `_1` and the second `_2`. If i name the service as `controller_g5` THe container name would be `controller_g5_1`

Comment: You don't need to worry about the numbers. Within a project, you can still use the service names as hostnames i.e., `controller_g5` will just work.